# can I set a wtforms DateTimeField to also accept just a Date value?

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'd like to let the user of my application enter either a Date or a DateTime.  Is there any way to achieve this with a single field?

```
dateCreated = DateField('Date created', validators[Required(message='Input must be of YYYY-MM-DD format.')])
```

and

```
sessionDate = DateTimeField('Date', validators=[Required(message='Input must be of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.')])
```

accept one or the other.  Is there any way to have a single field that will accept either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating a new field subclass, which will accept either date format and returns a `datetime.datetime` (but could easily be modified to return a `datetime.date`).

This implementation is based on `wtforms.fields.DateTimeField` ([source](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/3d5af963f060add8e42a99bec880321e8d2b41b3/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L813))

```
class LenientDateTimeField(Field):

    def __init__(self, label=None, validators=None, formats=None, **kwargs):
        super(LenientDateTimeField, self).__init__(label, validators, **kwargs)
        if formats is None:
            self.formats = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d']
        else:
            self.formats = formats
        self.format = None

    def _value(self):
        if self.raw_data:
            return ' '.join(self.raw_data)
        else:
            return self.data and self.data.strftime(self.format) or ''

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            date_str = ' '.join(valuelist)
            for fmt in self.formats:
                try:
                    self.data = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt)
                    # If a datetime.date is required, do:
                    # datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt).date() 
                    self.format = format
                except ValueError:
                    self.data = None
                else:
                    break
            if self.data is None:
                message = 'Value did not match any of these formats: {}'.format(', '.join(self.formats))
                raise ValueError(self.gettext(message))
```